# How to make view that add product working correct in django/python

Tags: python, django

I have view in django that add product to the cart( i use  django-carton 1.2). That my code:

```
def add(request,product_id):
   cart = Cart(request.session)
   product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
   if product.quantity >=1:
      cart.add(product, price=product.price)
      product.quantity-=1
      product.save()
      return render (request,'shopping/show-cart.html')
   else:
      return HttpResponse("No product ")
```

After that view has worked a certain product add to the cart, cart with all products is showing. The problem: when in browser I make function "reload current page" it increase quantity of products in my cart. At the same my remove product view is working, but it only try delete the product when page reload from the function of browser

Answer (score 0):

You should only do actions that modify data - like add and delete - on a POST request, not a GET. You need to create a form in your page, even if it just contains a single button, and check `if request.method == 'POST'` in the view before doing anything.

Comment: I have made in that way. When i reload page now Mozilla show this text "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier". And then I place resend, quantity increase

Answer (score 0):

Either include a form tag within your html that POSTS information or you can use an Ajax request call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#add_cart_button').click(function(e)
     {  
      $.ajax({

              url: 'xxxxxxx',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: {
                 'somevariable' : 'somevalue'
              },
              async: false,

              success: function(data){

                  $('#target').html(data);
              },


              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                  alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
              } 
          });
```

When you make the Ajax call, it sends whatever you have in your data dictionary to the specified url. From there, Django implements whatever function you want to process that data on the backend and returns the information back. The success function basically gets that information back and does whatever you want with it. In your case, you probably just want to re-render that chunk of HTML that displays the items in your cart.The target tag within the success function is where that chunk of HTML will be rendered, so include a target div tag in your html where you want it to be displayed.

You can access the data from the ajax request in your view by doing request.POST.get('key',somedefaultvalue) (if you want to have a default value if it can't find the dictionary or if it's empty) or just request.POST[key].